# Mapping legacy domain class using Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to map a legacy domain class to my grails class, but when table is generated, the field associated with legacy class is Tinyblob, and not a BigInt linked with ID, and foreing key stuff.

```
class NewClass implements Serializable {

  GrailsEntityA grailsEntityA
  GrailsEntityB grailsEntityB

  LegacyEntity legacyEntity

}
```

The table has foreing keys for **GrailsEntityA** and **GrailsEntityA** but not for **LegacyEntity**, the type is **tinyblob**, without relationship with the LegacyEntity table.

Is it possible do this? How?

Comment: Can you share the content of LegacyEntity too?

Comment: LegacyEntity is some class, from my hibernate system, can be any domain class used for JPA purposes

Comment: I think that you can create a custom [UserType](http://javadata.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/hibernate-and-user-types.html) that knows how to transform your tinyblob in LegacyEntity.

Comment: is LegacyEntity part of your Grails source code or you consume it as a binary dependency?

Comment: It is a binary dependency